# Is there a search tool for finding primary sources in US History?

Tags: research-process, online-resource, databases

If I search a tool like JSTOR, ProQuest, or Academic Search Complete, I typically just find secondary sources. Occasionally I can find primary sources there, but only when it is part of a translation or transcription project, but it is rare for me to find these appear in my results. Sometimes I can find books that compile these, but one $20 book might contain just 40 primary sources, which seems minuscule.

I'm looking for US History resources like letters, dairies, military orders, military reports, commission reports, etc.

Is there a search tool that compiles a vast database of primary sources?

Comment: I doubt it.  The vast vast majority of primary sources are still only available on paper in the sole original copy.  There's a reason that historians have to travel to do their research.